# How to make a generated code expire after a few times of entering (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have been trying to write a code in PHP that generates a random code, stores it in the database and asks the user to enter it. if the code is entered more than 3 times, the code needs to be expired. this is my code:

```
<?php
include("ProcessCode.php"); 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") ;
if(mysqli_select_db($con,"login"))
{
echo 'database  selected' ;
}

$rand=rand();
echo $rand ;

$sql = "INSERT INTO random (number) VALUES ('$rand') "  ;

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   echo 'inserted'  ;
}

?>
    $CodeCheck=$_POST['code'];

     //Establishing Connection with server
     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

      //Selecting Database
      $db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "login");

       //sql query to fetch information of registerd user and finds user match.
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from random WHERE number='$CodeCheck'");

       $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
         {
          echo " Code exists already.";
         }

      if($rows == 1)
       {
        header("Location: Success.php");

       }
     else
     {
      $error = " Code is Invalid";
      echo $error;
     }
```

could you please explain how to implement the expiry part?

Answer (score 1):

in your table you could have a field for count. When use login and login is wrong, add + 1 to your count. When user login successfuly, reset the count. If count meet +3, reset the code.

Answer (score 0):

i understand from your question that you need the logic on how to make the random_code expired after inserting from interacted users on your website 3 times ,assuming that , as long as the code is not expired he will be able to do his inserts and you may load it on your page .

i would do that through database queries .

**Please follow this instruction listed below**

**instructions :**

while your php page generate the random code , you may store it in database table with a auto reference key , for instance , 
assuming that you have randomly generated a code as below :

"Some random code here"

the above code which was generated by your php page have load it from mysql table called Random_Generated_Code , i would go to edit this table and add new field in it and call it generated_Code_Reference_Key  ( could be auto serial number ) to avoid any duplication as well make additional field called Expire_Flag which we are going to use later.

so once your page have loaded the above example code  , you should retrieve the generated_Code_Reference_Key along with it and keep it in hidden variable on your page 
it should be loaded on the page based on expire_Flag value as a condition
select generated_code from Random_Generated_Code  where expire_flag = ""

now once the user try to insert that generated code , in each time he insert it define another table in your database lets call it ( inserted_Codes_by_users) and store in it the username of whoever is doing that on your website as well you have to store the generated_Code_Reference_Key which we are storing in hidden variable as mentioned earlier to indicate which code was used while inserting.

now during page load or any event you want  you can find expired  code by make select statement from the inserted_Codes_by_users table

select count(generated_Code_Reference_Key) as The_Code_Used_Qty from inserted_Codes_by_users where username = username_of_that_user

so you can get how many times this user have inserted this specific generated_random_Code

retrieve result of the query in a variable and to make sense lets call it The_Code_Used_Qty  and make if condition on page load event or any event you like

if The_Code_Used_Qty = 3 then 
fire update statement to first table which loaded that random generated code
and update the expire_flag field for that code (Expired) based on reference_key

update Random_Generated_Code set expire_Flag = "expired" where generated_Code_Reference_Key = "generated_Code_Reference_Key" << the one u stored in hidden variable 
end if

so now that will get you directly to the point of why we are  loading random_generated_code table first time with that condition expire_flag = ""
as it will only retrieve the codes which is not expired .

hopefully this will help you to achieve what you want . 
good luck and let me know if you need any help or if you face any confusion while reading my answer.

Good luck .